Why tasklet is faster than workqueue?
Currently I have done some experiments to compare the latency of tasklet and workqueue.
Specifically, I wrote some kernel modules to simulate them, like this one:
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/ktime.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/random.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/workqueue.h>

#include <asm/cacheflush.h>

#define NUM_WORKITEMS 1  // Number of work items to schedule

static ktime_t work_start_time[NUM_WORKITEMS], work_end_time[NUM_WORKITEMS];
static struct workqueue_struct *my_workqueue; // Single workqueue
static struct work_struct works[NUM_WORKITEMS];

static void clear_cpu_cache(void)
{
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__i386__)
    smp_call_function_single(0, (smp_call_func_t)wbinvd, NULL, 1); // Trigger on all CPUs
#elif defined(CONFIG_ARM) || defined(CONFIG_ARM64)
    smp_call_function(clear_cache_all, NULL, 1);  // Call flush_cache_all() on all CPUs
#else
    pr_warn("Cache clearing not implemented for this architecture\n");
#endif
}

static void flush_disk_cache(void)
{
    struct file *f;

    f = filp_open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", O_WRONLY, 0);
    if (IS_ERR(f)) {
        pr_warn("Failed to open /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches\n");
        return;
    }

    kernel_write(f, "3\n", 2, &f->f_pos);
    filp_close(f, NULL);

    pr_info("Disk cache flushed via /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches\n");
}

static void clear_all_caches(void)
{
    clear_cpu_cache();     // Clear CPU caches
    flush_disk_cache();    // Clear disk I/O caches
}

// Function to get the voluntary and involuntary context switches of the current task
static void get_context_switches(struct task_struct *task, long *voluntary, long *involuntary)
{
    *voluntary = task->nvcsw;      // Voluntary context switches
    *involuntary = task->nivcsw;   // Involuntary context switches
}

static void work_handler(struct work_struct *work)
{
    int work_id = (int)((uintptr_t)work - (uintptr_t)works) / sizeof(struct work_struct);
    pid_t pid = current->pid;  // Get the current process ID
    long pre_voluntary, pre_involuntary;
    long post_voluntary, post_involuntary;

    // Get context switch counts before execution
    get_context_switches(current, &pre_voluntary, &pre_involuntary);
    
    // Simulate heavy computation
    long long i, counter = 0;
    unsigned long cpu_start_time = ktime_to_ns(ktime_get()); // Start CPU time
    
    int index;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        get_random_bytes(&index, sizeof(int));
        index %= 1000000;
        counter += index * index;
    }
    
    // msleep(100);

    work_end_time[work_id] = ktime_get(); // End wall time
    unsigned long cpu_end_time = ktime_to_ns(work_end_time[work_id]); // End CPU time
    
    pr_info("Work item %d executed on CPU %d\n", work_id, smp_processor_id());
    pr_info("Work item %d latency: %lld ns, "
            "computation cost (CPU time): %llu ns, counter = %lld\n",
            work_id,
            ktime_to_ns(ktime_sub(work_end_time[work_id], work_start_time[work_id])),
            cpu_end_time - cpu_start_time, counter);

    // Get context switch counts after execution
    get_context_switches(current, &post_voluntary, &post_involuntary);

    pr_info("Context switches before work: Voluntary = %ld, Involuntary = %ld\n", pre_voluntary, pre_involuntary);
    pr_info("Context switches after work: Voluntary = %ld, Involuntary = %ld\n", post_voluntary, post_involuntary);
}

static int __init single_workqueue_init(void)
{
    int i;

    // Create a single workqueue
    my_workqueue = alloc_workqueue("my_single_workqueue", WQ_UNBOUND, 0);
    if (!my_workqueue) {
        pr_err("Failed to create workqueue\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    clear_all_caches();

    // Initialize and queue multiple work items
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_WORKITEMS; i++) {
        INIT_WORK(&works[i], work_handler);
        work_start_time[i] = ktime_get(); // Record start time
        queue_work(my_workqueue, &works[i]); // Schedule work item on the single workqueue
    }

    pr_info("Single workqueue test module loaded\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit single_workqueue_exit(void)
{
    if (my_workqueue) {
        flush_workqueue(my_workqueue); // Ensure all work items are completed
        destroy_workqueue(my_workqueue); // Destroy the workqueue
    }

    pr_info("Single workqueue test module unloaded\n");
}

module_init(single_workqueue_init);
module_exit(single_workqueue_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Your Name");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Single workqueue with multiple work items");

This is my code for workqueue. I tried to avoid cache influence by flushing them (can you check this?) and randomizing. The results were that: When run multiple tests, the time for tasklets are quite similar. Meanwhile, the time for workqueue on one test can double another.

Here is an example, the length of segments illustrate their computation time.
At the first time, I think the reason is due to context switching in workqueue. But after I add function to print the number of switches, I see that the work is executed serially. Only when added msleep, the context switching is performed.
So I have no clue about this? Maybe there is another external factor affecting the results?
Or can you revise my experiment and provide suggestions?

While I am not an expert on this personally, from reading the related question it is pretty obvious that these results are exactly what you should expect.   Tasklets are intended to be low latency and so are more deterministic, work queues have more variable timing because you share the queue with more other things within the kernel.
